# Как подключить скрипт для нескольких Google таблиц

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть несколько типовых таблиц, в каждой из них прописан скрипт и прикреплён HTML шаблон, код постоянно дорабатывется, и очень не удобно вносить изменения в каждую таблицу. Возможно ли сделать, отдельный проект со скриптами который бы подгружался ко всем таблицам.
Примечание: отправка doGet(), не очень удобна, тк приходится много отлаживать и выполнение функций могут занимать много времени

Comment: Ттипа "задачу" нарезал?

Comment: Можете сохранить свой скрипт как библиотеку и использовать в любых других скриптах. Правда при изменении этой библиотеки - ей присваивается новый номер и во всех других скриптах у этой библиотеки нужно будет выбрать новую версию

Comment: а можно каким либо образом при помощи скрипта обновить эти ссылки на библиотеку?

Comment: О таком не слышал.

Comment: Задача может быть решена. Измените вопрос, чтобы он соответствовал правилам сообщества https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: oshliaer, добрый день обращаюсь как местному гуру google apps script, направьте где покапать, для решения этой задачи. она вновь стала актуальной